# Formatting the messages in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

HI,

I have the following code in my JSP file:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{jsfBean.name }" required="true"/>
<h:message for="name"/>
```

The error messages displayed is something like this:

```
j_id_jsp_1916142437_1:name: Validation Error: Value is required.
```

How can I format the output error message like giving the color,font,etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply By  applying CSS.

```
<h:message for="age" style="errorMessage" /></p>
```

You can also override default messages by providing Messages.properties file

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Please enter a value for this field.
    javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE=Please enter a valid date. 
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE_detail=Please enter a valid date. Example: {1}
```

**Also See**

- [Nice Article on Customizing error message](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/189-java-ee-5-development-using-glassfish-application-serve-3.html)

Comment: style="errorMessage" should be defined in the CSS file right?

Comment: What is the correct place to put the messages.properties file?

Comment: I have given like <h:message for="name" style="color:red;"/>. Its working fine. Now I want to format the message in the properties file.

Comment: you need to make Properties file's entry in `faces-config.xml` please check article it describes it very well

Comment: You didn't ask for it, but as extra advice, if you want to get rid of the ugly "j_id_jsp_1916142437_1:name:" on your output you can use the label attribute of h:inputText.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use style attribute in h:message component for user defined css styles

```
<h:inputText id="textNameId" label="Name" required="true" ></h:inputText>
<h:message for="textNameId" style="font-size: 11px; color: Green; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"></h:message>
```